# Angularjs change text according to true false status

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, filter

I am making a box with ng-repeat here is the html

```
<div class="mission_box clearfix" ng-repeat="mission in missions">
    <img src="images/tick_patch.png" class="expired_img">
    <h2>{{mission.name}}</h2>
    <p class="clearfix"><em>Win</em> <span><img src="images/crown.png"> {{mission.crownwin}} Crowns</span> <span><img src="images/voucher.png"> {{mission.voucherwin}} Voucher</span></p>
    <div class="progress_box_outer clearfix">
        <div class="progress_box">
            <span style="width:{{100/mission.tasktotal*mission.taskdone}}%"></span>
        </div>
        <p class="progress_count">{{mission.taskdone}}/{{mission.tasktotal}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="expiry_date">
        <p>{{mission.expiry | missionexpire}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the defined array in controller for this

```
$scope.missions = [
    {'name':'3 Start Checkins', 'crownwin':'100', 'voucherwin':'flipkart','tasktotal':'4','taskdone':'3','expiry':'Expire on 25/06','isexpired':false,'iscompleted':true},
    {'name':'3 Start Checkins', 'crownwin':'100', 'voucherwin':'flipkart','tasktotal':'4','taskdone':'2','expiry':'Expire on 25/06','isexpired':false,'iscompleted':true}
]
```

And filter i have created yet

```
.filter('missionexpire', function(){
    return function(input){
        if(input == true){
            input = 'Completed'
        } else {
            input = input
        }
    }
})
```

In the above code you can see the last div in html with class `.expiry_date` i have defined filter in that.

What exactly i want is to change the text of `{{mission.expiry}}` if the status of `{{mission.iscomplete}}` is true.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply achieve this without a `filter`. Just use a conditional expression like

```
<p>{{mission.iscompleted === true?'Completed': mission.expiry}}</p>
```

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  $scope.missions = [{
    'name': '3 Start Checkins',
    'crownwin': '100',
    'voucherwin': 'flipkart',
    'tasktotal': '4',
    'taskdone': '3',
    'expiry': 'Expire on 25/06',
    'isExpired': false,
    'iscompleted': true
  }, {
    'name': '3 Start Checkins',
    'crownwin': '100',
    'voucherwin': 'flipkart',
    'tasktotal': '4',
    'taskdone': '2',
    'expiry': 'Expire on 25/06',
    'isExpired': true,
    'iscompleted': false
  }, {
    'name': '3 Start Checkins',
    'crownwin': '100',
    'voucherwin': 'flipkart',
    'tasktotal': '4',
    'taskdone': '2',
    'expiry': 'Expire on 25/06',
    'isExpired': false,
    'iscompleted': false
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="AppController">
    <div class="mission_box clearfix" ng-repeat="mission in missions">
      <h2>{{mission.name}}</h2>
      <p class="clearfix"><em>Win</em>  <span>{{mission.crownwin}} Crowns</span>  <span> {{mission.voucherwin}} Voucher</span>
      </p>
      <div class="progress_box_outer clearfix">
        <div class="progress_box">
          <span style="width:{{100/mission.tasktotal*mission.taskdone}}%"></span>
        </div>
        <p class="progress_count">{{mission.taskdone}}/{{mission.tasktotal}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="expiry_date">
        <p>{{mission.iscompleted === true?'Completed': (mission.isExpired === true ? 'Expired' : mission.expiry)}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can i use something like else if in this as i want to add one more condition if `iscomplete` is false and `isexpire` is true then i need to write expired.

Comment: Check out my updated snippet. If you have more conditions its better to have a method that you evaluate it. If its just for these two statutes then the conditional above will do. If you think I answered your question, please mark it accepted!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve this by `filter` try this. From the `filter` you need to return anything.

```
.filter('missionexpire', function(){
    return function(input, iscompleted){
        if(iscompleted){
            return 'Completed';
        } else {
            return input;
        }
    }
})
```

and

```
<div class="expiry_date">
        <p>{{mission.expiry | missionexpire:misson.iscompleted}}</p>
    </div>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
$scope.missions = [
    {'name':'3 Start Checkins', 'crownwin':'100', 'voucherwin':'flipkart','tasktotal':'4','taskdone':'3','expiry':'Expire on 25/06','isexpired':false,'iscompleted':true},
    {'name':'3 Start Checkins', 'crownwin':'100', 'voucherwin':'flipkart','tasktotal':'4','taskdone':'2','expiry':'Expire on 25/06','isexpired':false,'iscompleted':true}
]
}])




app.filter('missionexpire', function(){
    return function(input, isCompleted){
        if(isCompleted){
            return 'Completed';
        } else {
            return input;
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='MyCtrl'>
  <div class="mission_box clearfix" ng-repeat="mission in missions">
    <h2>{{mission.name}}</h2>
      <p class="clearfix"><em>Win</em>  <span>{{mission.crownwin}} Crowns</span>  <span> {{mission.voucherwin}} Voucher</span>
      </p>
      <div class="progress_box_outer clearfix">
        <div class="progress_box">
          <span style="width:{{100/mission.tasktotal*mission.taskdone}}%"></span>
        </div>
        <p class="progress_count">{{mission.taskdone}}/{{mission.tasktotal}}</p>
      </div>
    <div class="expiry_date">
        <p>{{mission.expiry | missionexpire:mission.iscompleted}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To filter `content` according to a specific property value in `AngularJs` there are used `Pipes` ( | ) 
So, in your section:

```
    <div class="expiry_date">
        <p>{{mission.expiry | missionexpire}}</p>
    </div>
```

You add only the property but not the evaluation for that property. To do so you need to change that to,

```
    <div class="expiry_date">
        <p>{{mission.expiry | missionexpire:iscomplete}}</p>
    </div>
```